# selecting a item in a ordered list and changing the color, according with input text jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have an ordered list:

```
<ol id="selectable" class="list">
  <li class="ui-widget-content" id="l1">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" id="l2">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" id="l3">Item 3</li>
</ol>

<style>
  #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39805; color: white; }
</style>
```

And a dropdown component:

```
<select id="sel"></select>
```

First the dropdown is filled up with the values of the list. Then in every call of the onchange event from the dropdown, the selected option, should be also selected as item in the list and then marked with a diffrent background color. For example if option "Item 2" in the dropdown is selected, then "Item 2" schould be also selected in the list and should have a different background color that indicates that had been selected. 
I tryed like this, but the last part to give the color to the selected item in the list is not working.

```
//The dropdown is fill up with the content of each item of the list
$(".list li").each(function(key, value){
        var name = $(value).html();
        var real = name.split(" ");
        $("#sel").append(new Option(real[1],value.id)); 
});

$("#sel").on('change',function(){
        var selectedoption = $("#selectable");  
        var selectedelement;
        $(".list li").each(function(key, value){
            if($("#sel").val() == value.id){
                selectedelement = value;//selecting the item in the list
                $("#selectable").on("selectablestop", function(){$(".ui-selected", element);});//change the background color of the selected item
            }
});
```

Has somebody an idea what is here wrong? THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/3dyzqq1t/7/).

```
$(".list li").each(function(key, value){
        var name = $(value).html();
        var real = name.split(" ");
        $("#sel").append(new Option(real[1],value.id)); 
});

$("#sel").on('change',function(){
        var selectedoption = $("#selectable");  
        var selectedelement;
        selectedoption.find('li').removeClass('ui-selected');
        $('#' + $(this).val()).addClass('ui-selected');
    });
```

Hope this is what you need!